# Get basename from find arborescence?

Tags: unix, find

I'm using find to find a list of file but someone are in a subdorectories and I need to get only the filename.

Any idea on how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
your_find_command|awk -F"\/" '{print $NF}'
```

or

```
your_find_command -exec basename {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If not comfortable with awk, can go with cut command

```
your_find_command | rev | cut -d"/" -f1 | rev
```